# How does this quantisation relation come about?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, operators, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator

I'm currently doing a course in string theory and in the lecture notes it is stated:

$$ [x^-, p^+]~=~-i \tag{1}$$

I am fine with this. However, after trying (and failing) a question, I looked at page 23 in 't Hooft's notes: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/stringnotes.pdf

which state:
$$ [x^-, p^-]~=~+i\frac{p^-}{p^+} .\tag{2}$$

I cannot find any information on where this came from. Does anyone have a reference/ derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use

$$  p^-~=~\frac{1}{2p^+} \sum_{i=1}^{D-2} \left(  (p^i)^2 +\sum_{m\neq 0} \alpha^i_{-m}\alpha^i_m  \right) \tag{4.10}$$

in 't Hooft's [2004 string notes](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/stringnotes.pdf) to conclude that

$$ 0~\stackrel{(4.10)}{=}~[x^-, p^+p^-]~=~[x^-, p^+]p^-+p^+[x^-, p^-]. $$
Now use eq. (1) to deduce eq. (2).